Transfer LDAP with PHP to LDAP with Spring Security
I would like to switch my application from PHP to Spring, but I have the problem that I can't get the LDAP query to work.
This is my old PHP function for checking user credentials
public function checkuser($user, $password)
    {
        // check if a password is set
        if(strlen($password) < 1) { return false; }
        
        if(!extension_loaded('ldap')) { return false; }
        
        $con = ldap_connect('ldaps://ldap-idm2.mysystem.de', 636);

        ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        
        if(@ldap_bind($con, 'cn='.$user.',ou=users,o=grp', $password))
        {
            ldap_close($con);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ldap_close($con);
            return false;
        }
    }

Here is my attempt with Spring Security LDAP
public String doLogin(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response,
                          String username,
                          String password) {
        // Check user credentials
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            username,
                            password
                    )
            );

            SecurityContext securityContext = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
            this.securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(securityContext);
            this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);
            // set response to true
            return "true";
        }
        // if user credentials wrong
        catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
            // response error message
            return authenticationException.getMessage();
        }
    }

@Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider LdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = 
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("mysystem.de", "ldaps://ldap-idm2.mysystem.de:636", "ou=users,o=grp");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = 
            new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder());

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider, LdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

Now when I try to log in to LDAP I get the following error message:
org.springframework.ldap.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN Syntax]
        at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:136) ~[spring-ldap-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:224) ~[spring-security-ldap-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:167) ~[spring-security-ldap-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:79) ~[spring-security-ldap-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at willy.ldap.DoLogin.doLogin(DoLogin.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:196) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.23]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid DN Syntax]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3201) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2992) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2906) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:349) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:229) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:189) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:247) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:520) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236) ~[na:na]
        at java.naming/javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:403) ~[spring-security-ldap-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:217) ~[spring-security-ldap-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
        ... 106 common frames omitted

Can someone help me as to how I need to configure the LdapAuthenticationProvider correctly?
